# geoFire 4.1.2 / Angular 2 / 4.0.2, Firebxase 3.8.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

I am getting the below error for the following code:

```
...
import {GeoFire} from 'geofire';
...
@Component{
::::
}
export class AppComponent{

constructor() {

  var afRef = this.af.database; // AngularFire connection
 let afRefAny: any = afRef.list('locations/');
  GeoFire(afRefAny._ref);

  var geoQuery = afRefAny.query({
    center: [51.294, -0.245],
    radius: 1
  });
}
}
```

[image]

After solving the above, I wanted to use geoQuery to build a mapping solution.

Appreciate any help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
import * as GeoFire from 'geofire';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

constructor() {

  // Generate a random Firebase location
  const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('locations');

  // Create a new GeoFire instance at the random Firebase location
  const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
  const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [51.294, -0.245],
    radius: 1
  });
}
```